# CUDA sum to the right

Tags: cuda, reduction, prefix-sum

I am trying to implement sum reduction using CUDA, however I want the reduction to be to the right not to the left..
I wrote the below code, but I am not sure why it is not working

```
__global__ void reduce_kernel(
    float *input,
    float *partialSums,
    unsigned int N) 
{
    unsigned int segment = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * 2;
    unsigned int i = segment + threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ float input_s[BLOCK_DIM];

    input_s[threadIdx.x] = input[i] + input[i + BLOCK_DIM];
    int count = 2;
    __syncthreads();

    for (unsigned int stride = BLOCK_DIM / 2; 
         stride < BLOCK_DIM;
         stride = stride + (BLOCK_DIM / count)) 
    {
        if (threadIdx.x >= stride) {
            count = count * 2;
            input_s[threadIdx.x] += input_s[threadIdx.x - stride];
            printf("%d  ", stride);
            __syncthreads();
            if (stride == BLOCK_DIM - 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (threadIdx.x == BLOCK_DIM - 1) {
        partialSums[blockIdx.x] = input_s[threadIdx.x];
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doing exactly what you want as long as the input number of elements is a power of two. The partial sum should end up to the right. The stride in such an algorithm has to grow from `1` to `BLOCK_DIM / 2` (gives more warp divergences) or shrink from `BLOCK_DIM / 2` to `1`. Either way it should be doing so by being multiplied/divided by `2`.

```
__global__ void reduce_kernel(
    float *input,
    float *partialSums,
    unsigned int N) 
{
    unsigned int segment = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * 2;
    unsigned int i = segment + threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ float input_s[BLOCK_DIM];

    input_s[threadIdx.x] = input[i] + input[i + BLOCK_DIM];
    __syncthreads();

    for (unsigned int stride = BLOCK_DIM / 2; 
         stride > 0;
         stride /= 2) 
    {
        if (threadIdx.x >= BLOCK_DIM - stride) {
            input_s[threadIdx.x] += input_s[threadIdx.x - stride];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (threadIdx.x == BLOCK_DIM - 1) {
        partialSums[blockIdx.x] = input_s[threadIdx.x];
    }
}
```

The `__syncthreads();` inside the conditional is another error, as all threads of the block have to participate in the synchronization. Otherwise undefined behavior is caused.